# How can I get a specific tag from array returned from Net::Amazon::EC2 decribe_tags?

Tags: perl, ec2-api-tools

I'm using Net::Amazon::EC2 to get some information about my instances.

I get all of the tags associated with an instance with:

```
my $tags = $ec2->describe_tags("Filter.Name" => "resource-id", "Filter.Value" => $instance_id);
```

According to the docs, this returns an array ref of [DescribeTag](http://search.cpan.org/~mallen/Net-Amazon-EC2-0.22/lib/Net/Amazon/EC2/DescribeTags.pm) objects.

I can iterate through the results:

```
foreach my $tag (@$tags) {
    print $tag->key . " = " . $tag->value . "\n";
}
```

Is there a way I can get a tag with a specific key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably `grep` through them. Not very elegant, but I don't know the module you are using.

```
my @filtered_tags = grep { $_->key eq 'specific' } @$tags;
```

Comment: Not elegant, but it works.  If I wanted elegant, I probably wouldn't be using perl :)

Comment: @chris Perl is so flexible, you can develop *very* elegant code, IMO. The problem here is either a not-so-flexible or not fully understood API.

Comment: @memowe agreed. I did not understand the API at all. Never used it, in fact. Still, glad this works. Sometimes Perl is all about getting things done, so I feel not elegant is ok in some cases.